# Keeping unused variables in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I made some kernels for testing bandwidth and they do no useful computations. A minimal example is

```
__global__ void testKernel(float* a) 
{
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float x;
    x = a[i];
}
```

When I compile, I get (not surprisingly)

> warning: variable "x" was set but never used

and the kernel runs as quickly as an empty kernel:

```
__global__ void donothing() 
{
}
```

This indicates that the read of a[i] has been optimized out.

I have tried tricks such as

```
volatile float x;

if(x);

(void)(x;)
```

and they suppress the warning, but the kernel still finishes too quickly.

How can I make sure that the useless instructions actually get executed?

I found the option CU_JIT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL but google provides mostly links to the documentation and not how to use it. Would this option help me and how do I use it?

Comment: I have always made these things useful, so they can't eliminate it. Is this an option for you?

Comment: @Pavan that won't help. x is still unused.

Comment: @Patrick87 Using the data would take time and I only want to check the memory bandwidth

Answer (score 3):

Try introducing a branch which stores the variable:

```
__global__ void testKernel(float* a, float *b) 
{
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float x;
    x = a[i];

    if(b)
    {
      *b = x;
    }
}
```

The cost of the branch compared to the cost of memory transfer is negligible.

At the kernel launch site, simply pass a null pointer:

```
testKernel<<<...>>>(a, static_cast<float*>(0));
```

nvcc will not perform [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) at this granularity, so your load should not be removed because the compiler cannot prove it is useless.

Comment: You can also often use `if (threadIdx.x > -2) {}` or something else bogus like that to fool the compiler into keeping the code around.

Comment: Is it not possible to prevent the optimization without adding code that actually does something?

Comment: @stardt I don't know of a way to do it without introducing the possibility of using the loaded value in some way.